# python os.path.exists() can't locate the file however the file indeed exists

Tags: python

Here is my code, it can locate the file `ctfmon.exe`, but can't locate the file `cc.dll`.

```
   >>> import os
   >>> os.path.exists("c:\\windows\\system32\\ctfmon.exe")
   True
   >>> os.path.exists("c:\\windows\\system32\\cc.dll")
   False
```

however the file `cc.dll` indeed exists.

```
C:\Windows\System32>dir cc.dll
 驱动器 C 中的卷没有标签。
 卷的序列号是 B481-54FB

 C:\Windows\System32 的目录

2014/04/17  14:12                 0 cc.dll
           1 个文件              0 字节
           0 个目录  8,659,787,776 可用字节
```

Comment: Is windows not case-sensitive?

Comment: import os
print os.path.exists("c:\\windows\system32\cca.dll")

Comment: Is that cc.dll directory showing a file of zero bytes?

Comment: Try to list all the file of "c:\\windows\\system32\\" with os.listdir (https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir), maybe it will appear with a different name or maybe you program doesn't have the write to see the file

Comment: @TimCastelijns no it's not.

Comment: What happens when you try to open this file with `f = open("c:\\windows\\system32\\cc.dll")` ?

Comment: i have tyried the listdir.but there are no same size file .but i found a suspicious file which i can't find it in cmd.  but it have different size.confused..

Answer (score 4):

You are running a 32 bit version of python on a 64 bit version of Windows. When you launch a 32 bit applications in 64 bit Windows C:\Windows\SysWOW64 is mapped to C:\Windows\System32.

Comment: This is the correct answer, and it should be accepted. Use `ctypes` and `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection` to disable this mapping (https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2009-June/009263.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this example:

```
os.path.isfile("your address/your file")
```

it's from python documentation

`os.path.exists(path)`
Return True if path refers to an existing path. Returns False for broken symbolic links. On some platforms, **this function may return False if permission is not granted to execute `os.stat()` on the requested file, even if the path physically exists.**
maybe this is your problem.

Comment: thanks for help.but i just tried os.path.isfile.it still return false.And when i try the other dll file in the same directory,it suceed.

Comment: @marsen I'm sure `os.path.isfile` extends `os.path.exists` in some way :) That's hardly a definitive test

Comment: @maersen check the size of directory to figure out if python could recognize that dll file or not with os.path.getsize(path)

Comment: @marsen  check this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755303/python-cdll-cant-find-module)

Comment: i have tried the size ,there is no  same size file.but i find a Suspicious file which have the similar name but different size. i can't find the file in cmd

Comment: @marsen did you check that question ??

Answer (score -1):

try removing double slashes ..

```
import os
print os.path.exists("c:\\windows\system32\cca.dll")
```

or

```
print os.path.exists("""c:\\windows\system32\cca.dll""")
```

Comment: That won't work since then you have the iterable `c`, `:`, `\\`, `windows` `\s` `ystem32` etc.

Comment: Then you either did `r"C:\windows\system32\cca.dll"` or you did `"C:/Windows/system32/cca.dll"`

Comment: print os.path.exists("""c:\windows\system32\cc.dll""") this also worked

Comment: The best way to do this is with `os.path.join('c:\\','windows','system32','cca.dll')`

Comment: what if i want to check dyanamically many files comming from a file

Comment: What if you do? `\ ` is only an escape character in a string literal. A literal backslash doesn't become an escape character just because you read it into python :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50841/discussion-between-sundar-nataraj-and-adam-smith)

Comment: And you're right, in that example it works, since none of `\w`, `\s`, `\c` are escape characters. Heaven forbid you look for `"C:\windows\system32\nslookup.exe"` though :)